# Approach to generate Short Unique key like (AboU8N) in distributed environment?

Tags: random, uuid, guid, uniqueidentifier

I know a few of the approaches to generating unique identifiers :

*The first Naive approach would be just to put auto-increment on the database column, but it does not provide uniqueness in a distributed environment.*

*The second approach would be to use a central database only to generate unique IDs, but I don't think it will scale that much*

*The third approach would be to hash the given URL and generate a hash of it, but well it takes way more space and if I take the preceding part of it there is much chance of collision too.*

*The well-known approach nowadays is to use something like a Twitter snowflake that contains well mixture of epoch, worker, and sequencer, It scales well but it does not fulfill the problem of short identifier. All I can do with this is generate a base64 string and take the preceding part of it again I have a problem with collision.*

**Do you guys have worked with similar kinds of problems of short unique ID generation, for let's say not more than 8 characters long? if yes then what was or will be your approach to solving this kind of problem? I tried all of the approaches above for my link shortner app but it did not give me satisfactory results.**

All kinds of responses will be well appreciated regardless of any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

- 4-byte timestamp with millisecond precision
- 1-byte collision counter, in case you generate ID's faster than one per millisecond
- 3-byte node id (allowing 2<sup>24</sup>-1 = 16-million users)

Giving:

```
........tttttttt  (timetsamp)
......cc........  (collision counter)
nnnnnn..........  (node id)
```

Resulting in an 8-byte value:

```
0xnnnnnncctttttttt
```

Which can be stored in an `Int64`.

You can then convert 8-bytes into 8 characters.

If you're willing to use Unicode, you could get it into 4 "characters".